# confused about lfs sources installation

Tags: linux, make, source, lfs

I started to homemode Linux build using LFS book. I came to Part II. - Chapter 5 about "Constracting a Temporary System". I downloaded all needed sources to /mnt/lfs/sources. When i want to start build packages and install, i confused a thing.

I installed some packages from source on my past distro based systems. When we use make install to install compiled source, it's installing to system directories (or i know like that). So if i run make install for the lfs sources, will it install to host system's directory instead of lfs system directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read everything in LFS book carefully!

[Creating the $LFS/tools Directory](http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter04/creatingtoolsdir.html)

> All programs compiled in Chapter 5 will be installed under `$LFS/tools`
>   to keep them separate from the programs compiled in Chapter 6. ... 
>   Create the required directory by running the following as root:
>
> ```
> mkdir -v $LFS/tools
> ```
>
> The next step is to create a `/tools` symlink on the host system. This
>   will point to the newly-created directory on the LFS partition. Run
>   this command as root as well:
>
> ```
> ln -sv $LFS/tools /
> ```

[Introduction](http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter05/introduction.html)

> The files compiled in this chapter will be installed under the
>   $LFS/tools directory to keep them separate from the files installed in
>   the next chapter and the host production directories. Since the
>   packages compiled here are temporary, we do not want them to pollute
>   the soon-to-be LFS system.

[Build of binutils (part 1)](http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter05/binutils-pass1.html)

> Now prepare Binutils for compilation:
>
> ```
> ../configure --prefix=/tools            \
>              --with-sysroot=$LFS        \
>              --with-lib-path=/tools/lib \
>              --target=$LFS_TGT          \
>              --disable-nls              \
>              --disable-werror
> ```
>
> The meaning of the configure options:
>
> ```
>   --prefix=/tools
> ```
>
> This tells the configure script to prepare to install the Binutils programs in the /tools directory.
>
> ```
>  --with-sysroot=$LFS
> ```
>
> For cross compilation, this tells the build system to look in $LFS for the target system libraries as needed.

So if you do everything well (exactly as in LFS book) it should work well :)

Comment: Thanks! I understand now why we use symlinks.